# SQL Server : restricting data range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

The query below is supposed to show details for 2 types of products: DIS001 and DIS002.

When DIS002, this should "reset" the query, so that it only shows DIS001 products which were sold after that the date when DIS002 was sold.

To be honest, I'm not even sure if this is possible. I'll be grateful for any suggestions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Sales.RaisedDateTime AS [Date],
    Contacts.ContactID AS [Contact ID],
    Contacts.SiteID AS [Site ID],
    Sales.ProductID AS [Product],
    CASE 
       WHEN Sales.ProductID = 'DIS002' 
          THEN Sales.RaisedDate 
          ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2019-10-28', 101) + ' 00:00:00') 
    END AS [Start Date] 
FROM 
    ((Bookings.Bookings Bookings
INNER JOIN 
    Contacts.Contacts Contacts ON (Bookings.ContactID = Contacts.ContactID))
INNER JOIN 
    Sales.Sales Sales ON (Bookings.ContactID = Sales.ContactID))
WHERE
    (Sales.ProductID = 'DIS001' AND 
     Sales.RaisedDate >= MAX([Start Date])
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help understanding your question better.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different syntax's to solve this, but here is one:

```
;with DIS002 as (
    select ContactID, max(RaisedDate) as DIS002Date 
    from Sales.Sales 
    where ProductID = 'DIS002'
    group by ContactID
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Sales.RaisedDateTime AS [Date],
    Contacts.ContactID AS [Contact ID],
    Contacts.SiteID AS [Site ID],
    Sales.ProductID AS [Product]
FROM 
    ((Bookings.Bookings Bookings
INNER JOIN 
    Contacts.Contacts Contacts ON (Bookings.ContactID = Contacts.ContactID))
INNER JOIN 
    Sales.Sales Sales ON (Bookings.ContactID = Sales.ContactID))
LEFT JOIN 
    DIS002 on DIS002.ContactID = Sales.ContactID
WHERE
    Sales.ProductID = 'DIS001' AND 
    Sales.RaisedDate >= isnull(DIS002date,'1900-01-01')
```